# Working with hibernate with Intellij or Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, intellij-idea

We have a project that is due to start and we are getting into the Holy IDE wars that I want to avoid.

One of the main areas we will be working in is hibernate.

In the past I have worked with ORMS where we had a UML model and via MDA (model driven architecture) I could change the UML, which changed the classes and then created or evolved the database.

Can I do this with intelliJ or Eclipse? I know I would that eclipse is free but it may be the same cost as IntelliJ if I have to pay for a plugin that does this?

TIA

JD

Comment: Personally, I think it's a bad idea to autogenerate the entities for the single reason that you cannot add any code to the entities and they become an [anemic domain model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). Simple scenario: imagine you have a user class which contains the credentials and you want a `setPassword` method that hashes the plain text password and stores it in a field named `password_hash`. For this reason, I never autogenerate the entities (unless it's the 1st week of the project and I need to map an existing DB).

Comment: Hi Augusto. We had a lot of business logic associated with the entities so I am not just saying create solely classes with getters and setters. I am sure you can do the same in hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse does have a very good hibernate tool suite available @ http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html. But do not forget to remove the unwanted code that is appended in the auto generated files and do a thorough review of the files generated. The HQL editor in the tool suite is a good one to use.

Comment: Thanks. Does it provide UML modelling?

Comment: I hope you are asking about eclipse plugin for UML modelling.There is one available @ [link](http://www.objectaid.com/). Its free version can be used to generate pretty nice class diagrams.The premium version has some more features.